# Magento 2 : An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again

Tags: magento2

I am trying to perform order checkout on 2.4 EE and getting the below error:

An ID is needed. Set the ID and try again.

What can be the cause of this issue? I checked in the logs but can not see any error on this?

Comment: Thanks, As i have removed Amasty_Sorting in di.xml
Its working for me ,
Thank you!

Comment: Any Solution you found?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was Amasty_Sorting in di.xml

```
 <!-- save info about reservation for configurables -->
    <type name="Magento\InventoryReservations\Model\AppendReservations">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Sorting::ReserveQtyForParents"
                type="Amasty\Sorting\Plugin\InventoryReservations\Model\AppendReservationsPlugin"/>
    </type>
```

Removed this and resolved the issue.

To find out how to fix the issue I did a grep of the app directory to see which modules were tapping into OrderRepository

**grep -R 'OrderRepository' app**

Comment: not yet, still facing the issue :(

Comment: Please see above. The error occurs when a module is tapping into the OrderRepository on checkout. In this instance it was stock reservation

Comment: Did that resolve it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log completely. If you have overridden `placeOrder()` method, put it in try catch and trace the log. For my case, it was with customer save for guest user. With the help of the log, I fixed the customer assignment to the quote correctly and I could able to place the order.

Comment: What you did to fix this issue?